# Code sample for: Update<T>(sourceObject, targetObject, string[] exceptions)

Tags: c#, object, properties, enumerate

I want a generic update method which copies all properties of `sourceObject` to `targetObject` but not methods mentioned in `exceptions`.

Comment: Is it just methods not mentioned in exceptions.  If so, omit methods completely when using reflection by specifying the correct flag when getting properties from the types/instances thereof using reflection ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [`AutoMapper`](http://automapper.codeplex.com/)? It allows you to define custom mapping as well as auto mapping.

--edit--

Example:

Given following types:

```
public class Type1
{
    public int MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty3 { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty4 { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty5 { get; set; }
}

public class Type2
{
    public int MyProperty1 { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty2 { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty3 { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty7 { get; set; }
    public int MyProperty8 { get; set; }
}
```

To create a map which ignores 2 properties (MyProperty7 & MyProperty8):

```
var map = Mapper.CreateMap<Type1, Type2>().
            ForMember(dest => dest.MyProperty7, opt => opt.Ignore()).
            ForMember(dest => dest.MyProperty8, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Finally copy:

```
Type2 type2Variable = Mapper.Map<Type1, Type2>(type1Variable);
```

--edit2--

Mapping same types example:

```
var map = Mapper.CreateMap<Type1, Type1>().
            ForMember(dest => dest.MyProperty4, opt => opt.Ignore()).
            ForMember(dest => dest.MyProperty5, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

use:

```
Type1 anotherType1Variable = Mapper.Map<Type1, Type1>(type1Variable);
```

Comment: This is about different types while I'm gonna copy some properties of a single type.